# Issue with mutate_at() in R 3.6

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been using `dplyr::mutate_at()` without any problem. But after updating to R 3.6, it gives an error message. For example,

```
library(dplyr)
salary <-
  structure(
    list(S = c(13876, 11608, 18701, 11283, 11767, 20872), X = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), E = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), M = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
salary
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>       S     X     E     M
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 13876     1     1     1
#> 2 11608     1     3     0
#> 3 18701     1     3     1
#> 4 11283     1     2     0
#> 5 11767     1     3     0
#> 6 20872     2     2     1
```

### 3.5.3

Here, I am trying to apply `factor` function to each `E` and `M` column using `dplyr::mutate_at()`.

```
salary %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars("E", "M"), .funs = list(~factor))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>       S     X E     M    
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 13876     1 1     1    
#> 2 11608     1 3     0    
#> 3 18701     1 3     1    
#> 4 11283     1 2     0    
#> 5 11767     1 3     0    
#> 6 20872     2 2     1
```

I could get this output in the `3.5.3` version.

```
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.5
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] dplyr_0.8.0.1
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       fansi_0.4.0      utf8_1.1.4       crayon_1.3.4    
#>  [5] digest_0.6.18    assertthat_0.2.1 R6_2.4.0         magrittr_1.5    
#>  [9] evaluate_0.13    pillar_1.3.1     cli_1.1.0        rlang_0.3.3     
#> [13] stringi_1.4.3    rmarkdown_1.12   tools_3.5.3      stringr_1.4.0   
#> [17] glue_1.3.1       purrr_0.3.2      xfun_0.5         yaml_2.2.0      
#> [21] compiler_3.5.3   pkgconfig_2.0.2  htmltools_0.3.6  tidyselect_0.2.5
#> [25] knitr_1.22       tibble_2.1.1
```

### 3.6

However, when I run *exactly same code* in the other notebook with `R 3.6` version,

```
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.5
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] dplyr_0.8.1
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       knitr_1.23       magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5
#>  [5] R6_2.4.0         rlang_0.3.4      fansi_0.4.0      stringr_1.4.0   
#>  [9] tools_3.6.0      xfun_0.7         utf8_1.1.4       cli_1.1.0       
#> [13] htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.2.0       assertthat_0.2.1 digest_0.6.18   
#> [17] tibble_2.1.1     crayon_1.3.4     purrr_0.3.2      vctrs_0.1.0     
#> [21] zeallot_0.1.0    glue_1.3.1       evaluate_0.13    rmarkdown_1.12  
#> [25] stringi_1.4.3    compiler_3.6.0   pillar_1.4.0     backports_1.1.4 
#> [29] pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

I am getting the following error message.

```
salary %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars("E", "M"), .funs = list(~factor))
#> Error: Column `E` is of unsupported type function
```

---

This error occurs after I upgraded `R` a few days ago. Does this really happen due to upgrading `R`?

Or is there another reason?

Comment: Have you tried `salary %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars("E", "M"), factor)`?

Comment: @MarianMinar Thanks! It also works in 3.6.0. But do you know why `list(~factor)` becomes problematic in the latest version?

Comment: I'm glad it worked, because I have the older version and your code worked on my setup. I'm not sure exactly why, but in retrospect, I actually don't know why `list(~factor)` ever worked in the first place! It's probably an `rlang` thing, but it looks like they tied up a bug that your code was exploiting. After all. applying a function to a column already produces a list, so the `list()`, is redundant, if I understand this correctly.

Comment: I posted it as an [answer down below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56303877/10059841)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `salary %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars("E", "M"), factor)`. Using a `list()` wrapper is (probably) not necessary (or correct).

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why `funs()` or `list()` worked previously, but just using without wrapper seems much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I write my own answer because I got to know something.

I'm not sure why the error occurs here and not there, but I become to know why `list()` wrapper did not work after reading the help file closely.

I should not have written the syntax as `list(~function)`. In multiple transformation part of `?mutate_all`, it says that

```
# If you want to apply multiple transformations, pass a list of
# functions. When there are multiple functions, they create new
# variables instead of modifying the variables in place:
iris %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list(scale2, log))

# The list can contain purrr-style formulas:
iris %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~scale2(.), ~log(.)))
```

In other words, `list(factor)` and `list(~factor(.))` might be appropriate to use `list` wrapper. And this works in the latest `3.6.0` version.

```
salary %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars("E", "M"), .funs = list(factor))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>       S     X E     M    
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 13876     1 1     1    
#> 2 11608     1 3     0    
#> 3 18701     1 3     1    
#> 4 11283     1 2     0    
#> 5 11767     1 3     0    
#> 6 20872     2 2     1

salary %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars("E", "M"), .funs = list(~factor(.)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>       S     X E     M    
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 13876     1 1     1    
#> 2 11608     1 3     0    
#> 3 18701     1 3     1    
#> 4 11283     1 2     0    
#> 5 11767     1 3     0    
#> 6 20872     2 2     1
```

Since the example in my question has used only one function, I think not using `list` wrapper is the most reasonable choice.

When implementing multiple functions, one of the above two syntaxes might be chosen.